# External Data "from Access" produces different list of available queries/tables depending on user

Tags: excel, ms-access, ms-access-2007, excel-2007

I have a MS Access 2007 database with a number of tables and queries it is on a shared server; myself and my co-workers can access this file and edit it.

In Excel 2007, if I go to `Data: Get External Data: From Access` I can see a list of the queries/tables and select one to connect to.  Works great!

However, when my co-worker performs these same steps and connects to the same MS Access database (shared server) he is given a truncated list of tables and queries.  He doesn't get the full list like I do.

I can't see anything different about the queries he can view and the queries he cannot in Access.  We both login on the same thin clients with the same software and version and we both have access to the same Excel/Access files.

Really sort of stumped.  Any suggestions on where I can look?  It appears that he is not the only one, actually - I seem to have some `sudo` power over this MS Access file that my other co-workers do not share.

Comment: MS Access is a file level database (not server level), so databases exist in individual files. Pay very close attention to the directory and file you and other users select. Did you sit at co-worker's desk and reproduce issue or just accept his claim? He might have selected a copy (or even same name in different folder) that has less amount of objects. If you can, screenshot what you and your coworkers see.

Comment: @Parfait - he did send me a screen shot, we aren't side by side, but we walked though the steps together.  There is only one file in that folder and one database to choose.  This issue was discovered, actually, after we found that some excel linked tables I had created he was unable to refresh (it would say the query could not be found).  So we started from scratch ... which led us to realize even when he is linking the tables he can't see them.